# Select only checkbox inside a span

Tags: jquery, select

For a project I'm working on making a checklist. The idea is that visitors can select only one checkbox, the reason I'm not using radio buttons is beacause I need the checkboxes (checklist).

The problem I am having that I can't figure out the selector. I got 1 main question and 3 subquestions. All the questions are in spans so I can make them unique but I can't recall how to propper select it.

```
$('span .sub_antwoord').click(function() {
    $('span .sub_antwoord').each(function() {
        $(this)[0].checked = false;
    });
    $(this)[0].checked = true;
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle for the project http://jsfiddle.net/Ur4X9/ If you click through the checkboxes you can see the problem. I need to select one of each question, ja or nee.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show anything

Comment: It does in right top corner :) but not very obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
$('span .sub_antwoord').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked',false); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ur4X9/4/

Comment: for setting attribute values to `true` or `false`, you should be using jQuery `.prop()` instead of jQuery `.attr()`.  If you wanted to use `.attr()`, you should be using it as `.attr('checked', 'checked')`

Comment: Yup this is what I was looking for. So just for me to understand it completly. The this selector selects the span where the checkboxes are in yea? The siblings select one of the input buttons in the span and check if it's well checked or not.

Comment: `this` selects the checkbox being clicked on, then it looks around for siblings (at same level), specifically `input`, and then unchecks it. it works because your YES and NO `input`s are paired in the `span`s.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to set the checked property directly. Use this:

```
// deselect all checked boxes
$('span .sub_antwoord:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ur4X9/3/

#### html

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

#### JavaScript

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

​

​